# How to remove blue from an image using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I have this map with a blue square I would like to remove: [image: sample here]

I've tried using open cv to do so but I've been wildly unsuccessful. I used the solution here to no avail. The output looks exactly like the original. The blue square is the one intersecting with the red one at the bottom right. That's what I want to remove.

Here is my latest attempt:

```py
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ImageOps    
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imsave
import cv2
    
in_path  = 'map.jpeg'
out_path = 'new_output.jpeg'
       
Image = cv2.imread(in_path)
Image2 = np.array(Image, copy=True)
    
white_px = np.asarray([0, 0, 255])
black_px = np.asarray([255  , 255  , 255  ])
    
(row, col, _) = Image.shape
    
for r in range(row):
    for c in range(col):
        px = Image[r][c]
        if all(px == white_px):
           Image2[r][c] = black_px
    
imsave(out_path, Image2)
```

Comment: What are you hoping to replace the currently blue pixels with? White? Black? A guesstimate of what was there depending on surroundings?

Comment: follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69957383/how-can-i-isolate-rectangles-in-an-image-while-ignoring-background-noise-fuzz-fo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a test image like this:

```
magick -size 400x200 gradient:magenta-lime -stroke blue -fill none +antialias -draw "rectangle 10,10 390,190" a.png
```

[image]

Now there are a couple of ways you can approach this. You could replace all blue pixels with white:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load image
filename = 'a.png'
im  = cv2.imread(filename)

# Method 1: Simplistic overpaint blue with white
im[np.all(im == (255, 0, 0), axis=-1)] = np.uint8([255,255,255])
cv2.imwrite('result-white.png', im)
```

[image]

Or, maybe slightly better suited to the upper half of this image, replace blue with magenta:

[image]

---

Or you could *"inpaint"* - what **Photoshop** calls *"Content Aware Fill"* - which means that replacement pixels are guesstimated using the surrounding area:

```
# Method 2: Inpaint - or Photoshop "Content Aware Fill"
im  = cv2.imread(filename)
# Make mask of blue pixels - True where blue, False elsewhere
mask = np.all(im == (255, 0, 0), axis=-1)

# Inpaint white areas and save
# Options are: cv2.INPAINT_TELEA or cv2.INPAINT_NS
result = cv2.inpaint(im,np.uint8(mask)*255,3,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
cv2.imwrite('result-TELEA.png',result)
result = cv2.inpaint(im,np.uint8(mask)*255,3,cv2.INPAINT_NS)
cv2.imwrite('result-NAVIER-STOKES.png',result)
```

That gives this result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked well. I can't get it to work on JPG files for some reason. Is there a reason for that do you know?

Comment: Yes, JPEG files are **LOSSY**. They change your pixels to something that looks similar but can be saved in less space - that's why you shouldn't use them for technical, accurate purposes. So with a JPEG the test for blue , i.e. `np.all(im == (255, 0, 0), axis=-1)` doesn't work, because your blue (`255,0,0`) might have become `253,2,3`. You'll need to use use `cv2.inRange()` with suitable values to find the blues. It's getting late here, I'll update my answer later or tomorrow.

Comment: Quick untested attempt. Make `lo=[245,0,0]` and `hi=[255,10,10]` and do `mask = cv2.inRange(im, lo, hi)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Another question - if I wanted to thicken the grey line or make it black, which HSV would I put to convert to black?

Comment: I haven't analysed the image with a view to doing that, but I guess the whites are 220+ and the greys are maybe 180 or so. So if you threshold at say 200, all the greys below that would become solid black and all the near whites above 200 would become solid white. Run a colour picker over your greys to see what's a good threshold.

Answer (score -1):

just  assign blue channel to zeros

```
src = cv2.imread('D:/original.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
src[:,:,0] = np.zeros([src.shape[0], src.shape[1]])
cv2.imwrite('D:/no-blue-channel.png',src)
```

Comment: Mmmm... I predict a yellow image with black and red lines.

Comment: You predict correctly. When I tried this method that's exactly what happene. I'm not neccessarily trying to remove the blue channel. But rather the actual blue line. Thank you for your answer @Yash Talaiche but it's not 100% what I'm looking for.