# How can I isolate rectangles in an image while ignoring background noise/fuzz for training a neural net?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning

I have a population of images of maps (4tb worth - 670K images total). The maps are made up of overlain images of different maps. The boundaries of each map signified by a red, blue, or grey boundry. The solution I'm trying to come up with a solution that answers these two questions:

1. Does the map contain red lines that are not on top of grey lines.
2. If the answer to 1 is yes, are there portions of the red square located inside of blue squares?

I aim to build either a CNN or a script that will answer these questions by:

1. Recognizing images with intersecting red/grey lines.
2. Recognizing images with red lines inside the blue lines.

My first step (and please feel free to criticize my approach) is to take a map and mask the blue lines therein.

[image: starting point]

```
#Inpaint - or Photoshop "Content Aware Fill"
im  = cv2.imread('Sample2.png')
# Make mask of blue pixels - True where blue, False elsewhere
mask = np.all(im == (255, 0, 0), axis=-1)

# Inpaint white areas using Navier Strokes
result = cv2.inpaint(im,np.uint8(mask)*255,3,cv2.INPAINT_NS)
cv2.imwrite('result-NAVIER-STOKES.png',result)
```

This provides this output. [image: this output]

Next, I want to create an image containing a white background with the squares as black which I then hope to use to train a NN or write a script to identify if the squares intersect. In order to do that, I will need to further pre-process the image to look as close to this as possible (in cases where no grey square exists it would be only one square):

[image]

I've played around with masking to remove the noise and only isolate the grey and red rectangles but it seems like what I've written can only produce an output that isolates the red rectangle only:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
filename = 'output.PNG'
im = cv2.imread('output.PNG')
output_file = (os.path.splitext(filename)[0])
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = (0,240,160)
upper = (120,255,255)
thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9,9))
clean = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (15,15))
clean = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
# get external contours
contours = cv2.findContours(clean, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
result1 = im.copy()
result2 = im.copy()
for c in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(result1,[c],0,(0,0,0),2)
    # get rotated rectangle from contour
    rot_rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rot_rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    # draw rotated rectangle on copy of img
    cv2.drawContours(result2,[box],0,(0,0,0),2)
```

[image: Only the red square]

How can I isolate the grey square as well as the red square? I know it's a challenge because the map in the background is similar in coloration to the grey line. Is there a way to isolate the grey square an perhaps change its color to something other than grey to apply an additional mask?

Also if there's a better way to approach this problem, would love to hear thoughts and suggestions.

Comment: NNs are complete overkill for this. you also don't need inpainting. I saw your other question, and you got that answer because you asked the genie, and the genie gave you the answer to your literal question, which is useless to you. you didn't explain *why* you needed that. -- you really need to give a proper explanation that isn't dumbed down or "hiding" anything behind polite abstraction. your vague terminology in the first paragraph is already an indication that you haven't communicated the meat of the matter.

Comment: how would you even know if a red rectangle is on top of gray lines? the red lines would hide the gray lines. *what do you mean?* -- assuming there's at most one red and at most one blue rectangle per picture -- you need to generate one mask for each color, then take the bounding box for each. then you can calculate with those. intersection test of two rectangles is trivial.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz The problem I was facing in my previous question turned out to be because I was using JPGs instead of PNGs as you will see in the comments. As you can see, image processing is new to me. I'm trying to piece together the solution the best I can.

Also I agree that NN is an overkill for this problem. I know how to calculate if two rectangles intersect. What I don't know how to do is isolate the red and grey rectangles in a way that allows me to do so because the pixels of the underlying maps match the color of the pixels in the rectangles.

Comment: yes, that non-contrasting "color" is an issue. if you're lucky, you might be able to assume that the map is always lighter than the gray rectangle. that'll give you some margin. apart from that, it could be possible to process this with some morphology operations that would preserve the rectangle (vertical/horizontal lines of minimum thickness)... or at least most of its sides, which is good enough for a bounding box, assuming there is at most one such gray rectangle.

Comment: I inspected the first picture more closely. the gray rectangle is rather precisely `0.8` gray (204), while map-gray can be lighter or darker than that... so you'd want to inRange exactly that gray value AND also erode/dilate with a kernel that contains a vertical/horizontal line of width 2. that'll remove any other noise from the map.